# Google Leaderboards, Reducing the Score of a Player

Tags: android, leaderboards, google-play

I am making a strategy game similar to chess for Android.

I'll be using the Google Leaderboards for rankings.

I want to implement a sort of ranking system, that the player can actually lose score, similar to the one in www.chess.com.

But, from the docs of `submitScore()`:

**"The score is ignored if it is worse than a previously submitted score for the same player."**

I don't understand how can I implement such a system with Google Leaderboards.. sorry if I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: I'd look into the ability to remove the score of a player. Then you can simply do a remove, and add the new lower score.

Comment: I actually already did, but unfortunately, the only thing I found was the possibility to completely hide a player's score. (via the REST API) :(

Comment: I wonder whether the Swarm allows this (the docs say nothing - www.swarmconnect.com).

Answer (score 2):

Google Leaderboards saves the highest score, it can't simply reduce the score.

Your best bet is to create your own leaderboard system, which would allow you to remove/add score when needed.